# Optimize query mysql execution time

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a mysql query

```
 SELECT us.recNo, CONCAT(us.firstname,"",us.lastname) as fullname, max(dy.date) as Diarydate
 FROM users us JOIN diary dy on us.recNo = dy.clientID AND dy.date > (SELECT max(DATE(dateTime)) FROM `history` WHERE userID=us.managerID) OR dy.date is NULL
 WHERE us.managerID = 6 and us.accountStatus = 2 and us.securityGroup = 50 
 GROUP BY us.recNo, fullname
 ORDER BY fullname
```

But the execution time is very bad which makes the page load slower.
Can someone tell me how to get it done fast and improve the query?

Comment: [Indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)! Show the output of `show index from users`, `show index from diary` and `show index from history`.

Comment: And run your query with explain to see what your DB is doing in the background. Is the last order by really needed?